# Is there a way to restrict the packages installable from a repository?

Tags: package-management, repository, pinning

I want to restrict the packages installable from a repo, eg restrict some packages to the  main Ubuntu repos, even if they are available from launchpad or some other third party repos, something like `pinning` some packages to certain repository.

Normally the repository last added repo takes over all the packages which were available in other earlier repos.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to only allow specific packages updates from a PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96587/is-it-possible-to-only-allow-specific-packages-updates-from-a-ppa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set up AptPreferences for a set of packages add a new file in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/`.

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/preferences.d/my-packages-pin
```

Add add the following lines in that file:

```
Package: package1 package2
Pin: release o=Ubuntu
Pin-Priority: 900
```

I will prevent ppa versions to replace packages provided by the main Ubuntu archives

To check if the package pin version run:

```
sudo apt-cache policy package1
```

Visit https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: You're right, sorry about that. I'll elaborate a better answer.