# how to install lxterminal 0.2.0-1 (vivid) in Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, lxterminal

How to install this specific version of LXterminal in Lubuntu?
I have tried synaptic package manager but it tells me that my lxterminal it's up to date.

EDIT: I am interested in this version because it allows in the settings to change copy and paste keyboard commands. If there is a more recent version that does that I'd rather install that.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please edit your question to explain why you want the 0.2 version of lxterminal? Is there some significant improvement over the default? And where can this information be found?

Answer (score 1):

Please visit https://launchpad.net/~lubuntu-dev/+archive/ubuntu/lubuntu-daily. Here you'll find a collection of `ppas` (Personal Package Archives) provided by Lubuntu's development team. If you need to know more about ppas, you can look at [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983/248158). You may also want to know about how to remove a ppa: [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/q/307/248158).

Now to the specifics ...

The first link I provided offers an *Overview of published packages* along with a filter: in your case, you'd filter for "Trusty". You'll see that 62 packages are available for Trusty. One of them is `lxterminal`.

[image]

Let's assume you go ahead and install this ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lubuntu-dev/lubuntu-daily
```

You'll then need to run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

to update your software sources.

At the next step,

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**all** the existing software on your system will be upgraded to the version offered by the daily ppa, not just `lxterminal`!

If you really want only lxterminal, you'll need to do a bit more work. You'll need to issue commands preventing upgrading of anything else. And that's covered here: [Is it possible to only allow specific packages updates from a PPA](https://askubuntu.com/q/96587/248158).

By the way, since you've mentioned "vivid" in the title of your question, you can run a filter using vivid instead of trusty. As of today, both trusty and vivid have the same version of lxterminal, AFAICT.